# Solidity — refactor simple contracts to fix gas limit and avoid Checks-Effects-Interaction warning

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security, gas-price

The following pattern is something that recurs a lot in the contracts I am develping and when I run an analyser over it I get a couple of warning.

Say I have two contracts as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;


contract Candy {
    address public owner;

    function Candy() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

and

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import './Candy.sol';


contract Wrapper {

    Candy private candy;
    address public owner;

    function linkTest(Candy _candy) public {
        require(address(_candy) != 0x0);
        address candyOwner = _candy.owner();
        require(candyOwner != 0x0);
        owner = candyOwner;
        candy = _candy;
    }
}
```

The first warning is that `linkTest` includes a potential violation of the Checks-Effects-Interaction pattern.

My understanding of that is that if `_candy` was some unknown incoming address and not something explicitly castable to `Candy` then this might be an issue, but the two contracts are quite tightly coupled.

To mitigate this I ensure that any update to state is done after any `require` but the warning still shows and I am not sure how I'd refactor this to elimiate that.

The second warning is that the Gas requirement of `linkTest` is unknown or not constant. This is because of the call to `_candy.owner()`.

How would I refactor this to elminate both warnings? Is there a way I can proscribe an upper bound to the gas requirement for `_candy.owner()`?